# How to validate a dropdown list based on selection of another dropdown list

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, kendo-ui

I am having two dropdowns in my view,one dropdown indicating start year and another indicating end year.
I need validate start year should be less than end year.
Is there anything i can do with onblur event?
Please suggest me some functionality.
Thanks!

Comment: You can get the selected start year from first dropdown and pass to jquery on click event on second dropdown.There you can make the comparision between obtained start year value and currently selected value.And then go for ajax call as per you require.

Comment: well..i tried this way...but i guess i missed something in my functionality..i ll try again

Answer (score 1):

You can use change event of dropdown which will be firing when select a value from dropdown.
I have implemented it using JSON and jquery :

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#<%= cboDate.ClientID %>').change(function () {
               if( $('#<%= cboDate.ClientID %>').value >$('#<%= cboDate1.ClientID%>').value)
               alert('Messsage');

            });
        });
```

Comment: what is `.ClientID`?

Comment: ClientID is the ID given for the dropdown. for eg : <input type= DropdonList   ID="myDropdown"/>.  Here myDropdown is the client id